# How to separate rows of a csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv

I'm having a problem in rewriting a CSV file. What I had was a CSV file with 20 columns and I rewrote it to only 5. Now, I need to take out a couple of unnecessary points, where SN < 20. It works, the only problem is that it doesn't separate the rows. It puts everything in row 1. I'm guessing that its from the,

```
output_ary.append(row)
```

but I don't know what else to write there. Here is a part of the code:

```
import csv
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

os.chdir("C:\Users\Robert\Documents\qwe")

r = csv.reader(open("gdweights_feh_robert_cmr.csv",'rU'))

w = csv.writer(open("gdweight.csv",'wb',buffering=0))

zerovar2 = 0
for row in r:
        if zerovar2==0:
        zerovar2 = zerovar2 + 1
    else:
                sn = float(row[11])
                rweight = float(row[17])
                tarweight = float(row[18])
                fehadop = float(row[25])
                weight = rweight*tarweight*fehadop
                w.writerow([sn,rweight,tarweight,fehadop,weight])



output_ary = []

with open("gdweight.csv",'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter= ',')
    zerovar = 0
    for row in reader:
        if zerovar==0:
                zerovar = zerovar + 1
        else:
                sn = row [0]
                zerovar = zerovar + 1
                x = float(sn)
                if x > 20:
                    output_ary.append(row)

with open("ouput1.csv",'w') as f2:
    for row in output_ary:
        for item in row:
            f2.write(item + ",")
```

Comment: Why are you not using the `csv.writer` instead of writing to the file directly? There is much more to writing a csv file than just writing commas between two strings...

Comment: BTW, your indentation looks really weird.  Lots of times indentation doesn't survive pasting into SO, but you might want to (1) run your code using `python -tt your_program_name.py` to make sure it's not inconsistent, and (2) switch to using four spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: for those (as I was) wondering what -tt means, you can find it here : http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("ouput1.csv",'w') as f2:
    for row in output_ary:
        for item in row:
            f2.write(item + ",")
        f2.write("\n") # this is what you're missing
```

Comment: That was so simple that I just could not think of it. Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 0):

Simple rewrite the last as :

```
with open("ouput1.csv",'w') as f2:
    for row in output_ary:
        f2.write(",".join([str(e) for e in item] + '\n')
```

Now here are a couple of additional comments :

you can use enumerate instead of using a counter :

```
for i_row, row in enumerate(r) :
    ...
```

you can also use a csv writer :

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as f :
    csv_w = csv.writer(f)
    for i_row, row in enumerate(output) : 
        if i_row== 0 :
            continue
        csv_w.writerow(row)
```